# First array elements lost in loop C++

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm facing a weird behavior. I process some data in a loop, then if it meets certain criteria, I put the values into an array, but since I don't know the size of the data meeting the criteria, my declaration is `double arr[][4] = {0}` (if not initialized, I receive an error).

With test data, I know the size must be 1852 x 4. The problem is, if I define the array inside the function, the first 52 elements become 0 after some loop cycles, but always the first 52.

Using `printf`, I catch the very first element get lost after a `y` loop change, along the other processed in that "loop cycle", but I'm not touching the array variable outside the IF statement, so, I don't get why ONLY the first data is losing, those loop cycles have nothing special.

Besides, if I declare the array outside the function, no data get lost, but after 83 elements collected I receive the error "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)".

The total code is too large, but the involved is something like next:

```
double arr[][4] = {0};   // if declared here Segmentation Fault

float process(data){
  double arr[][4] = {0};   // if declared here first elements losing  
  for(int y = 0; y < 800; y++){
     for(int x = 0; x < 500; x++){
        /* do some stuff */
        if (prop>=criteria and prop<=criteria2){
            arr[cont][0] = prop;
            arr[cont][1] = y;
            arr[cont][2] = xx;
            arr[cont][3] = pixp;
            cont++;
            printf("%lf  %lf  %lf  %lf  \n", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2], arr[0][2]);
            //looking for the losing moment of first row
        }
      }  
   }
}
```

Also, if I declare an array "big enough", like `arr[20000][4]`, I still get losing data or segmentation fault, but with a weirder behavior, since the segmentation fault comes at 2105 elements collected (more than the actual ones meeting the criteria).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Include output and expected output in the quesiton

Comment: Arrays do not grow as you access higher index elements. For example an `int x[1];` has exactly 1 `int` element, at `x[0]`. It is an error to access `x[1]`, it does not extend the array.

Comment: `double arr[][4] = {0};` in the function declares a whole new array called `arr`. This hides the global `arr` array.

Comment: Its rather unclear how you know that you "loose" some array elements or how you know that the first 52 become 0 at some point. Your `printf` prints the same 4 elements in each iteration

Comment: @idclev463035818 "*Your printf prints the same 4 elements in each iteration*" - presumably the `/* do some stuff */` is changing the value of those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ arrays do not grow dynamically.  You are going out of bounds of your array, which causes *undefined behavior*.

When you don't know up front how many elements you are dealing with, use a `std::vector` instead.  In this case, I would say to use a vector of `struct` elements instead, since you are storing 4 `double` values per loop iteration, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct myValues {
    double prop;
    double y;
    double xx;
    double pixp;
};

float process(data){
  std::vector<myValues> arr;
  for(int y = 0; y < 800; y++){
     for(int x = 0; x < 500; x++){
        /* do some stuff */
        if (prop >= criteria && prop <= criteria2){
            myValues val;
            val.prop = prop;
            val.y = y;
            val.xx = xx;
            val.pixp = pixp;
            arr.push_back(val);
            printf("%lf  %lf  %lf  %lf  \n", val.prop, val.y, val.xx, val.pixp);
        }
      }  
   }
}
```